# Why cannot bind ‘const char*’ lvalue to ‘const char* const&&?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am doing exercises on "C++ Primer 5th" ex16.63 and 64, and the description about these exercises is following.

Exercise 16.63: Define a function template to count the number of occurrences of a given value in a vector. Test your program by passing it a vector of doubles, a vector of ints, and a vector of strings.

Exercise 16.64: Write a specialized version of the template from the
previous exercise to handle vector< const char* > and a program that
uses this specialization.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// ex16_63
template<typename T>
std::size_t VecCount(const std::vector<T> &vec, const T &&val){
    std::size_t num = 0;
    for(auto i: vec){
        if(val == i) ++num;
    }
    return num;
}

//ex16_64
template<>
std::size_t VecCount(const std::vector<const char*> &vec, const char* const &&val){
    std::size_t num = 0;
    for(auto i: vec){
        if(val == i)++num;
    }
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    // ex16_63
    std::vector<int> nVec = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<double> dVec = {3.14, 2.24, 3.14};
    std::vector<std::string> sVec = {"hello", "python", "python"};
    std::cout << VecCount(nVec, 1) << ' '
              << VecCount(dVec, 3.14) << ' '
              << VecCount(sVec, std::string("python")) << std::endl;

    // ex16_64
    std::vector<const char*> cVec = {"world", "turing", "turing"};
    const char *p = "turing";
    std::cout << VecCount(cVec, p) << std::endl; // wrong
    //std::cout << VecCount(cVec, std::move(p)) << std::endl; // correct
    return 0;
}
```

There's an error while compiling `ex16_64`:

```
error: cannot bind ‘const char*’ lvalue to ‘const char* const&&’ std::cout << VecCount(cVec, p) << std::endl;
```

I don't understand that my code about `ex16_64` is wrong without `std::move`, while my code about `ex16_63` is correct.

Comment: Why are you passing `val` as an rvalue reference into `VecCount()`? The function has no need for an rvalue reference.

Comment: `const T &&` is not a universal reference. Neither is `const char* const &&`. They're both rvalue references.

Comment: @Sneftel en...I understand, and I am just curious about what wil happen by passing val as rvalue reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lvalues cannot bind to rvalue references. That's the general rule. As such, it applies to all types, including `const char*`.

The reason why your code for 16.63 works is that you happen to pass rvalues in: `1` and `3.14` are rvalues because they're non-string literals. `std::string("python")` is an rvalue because it's a temporary.

`p`, on the other hand, is an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this instead:

```
std::cout << VecCount(cVec, std::move(p)) << std::endl;
```

The std::move function returns an rvalue. The code runs and produces:

```
1 2 2
2
```